# How would I make user be able to post and keep it on the site?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

here is the code that I need help with

I want to be able to post text on this website and for it to stay

https://pastebin.com/JcnNkRKx

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Negulos</title>
    <style>
      p {
        text-align: center;
        color: lime;
        font-size: 20px;
      }
      body {
        background-color: black;
        overflow-x: hidden;
      }
      input[type=text], select {
        boarder: none;
        background-color: black;
        color: lime;
        position: absolute;
        right: 550px;
      }
      div {
        border-radius: 5px;
        padding: 20px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Welcome to Negulos the current time is</p><p id="t"></p>
    <p>Write anything you'd like to get off your chest</p>
    <div>
      <input type="text" id="user" value="Your text here">
    </div>
    <p onclick="post" onmouseover="colorOn(this)" onmouseout="colorOff(this)">post</p>
    <p id="post"></p>
    <script>
      function colorOn(x) {
        x.style.color = "red";
      }
      function colorOff(x) {
        x.style.color = "lime";
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      function post() {
        var x = document.getElementById("user").value;
        document.getElementById("post").innerHTML = x;
      }
    </script>
    <script>
      document.getElementById("t").innerHTML = Date();
    </script>
    <?php

?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use ajax  ?! or may be I didn't get what you want right

Comment: what's the relation to php here?

Comment: and what do you mean by *"and keep it on the site?"* - ??

Comment: `onclick="post"` that's failing you here. You're obviously wanting to call the `post()` function here and omitted the `()` from it.

Answer (score 3):

This part of your code doesn't do anything:

- `<p onclick="post"`

You left out the brackets `()` which is supposed to trigger the `post()` function.

That needs to read as:

- `<p onclick="post()"`

Comment: how would I get it to go on multiple lines?

Comment: @Negulos that's a different story. You'd have to append to it.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've already tagged the question jQuery and PHP, the most common way would be to have some sort of api endpoint on the server, receiving the post requests, and using `$.post()` via jquery to send up the data. This could be triggered by event handlers, or any other method you choose.

The traditional way would be to create a html form, which automatically posts up the data:

```
<form method="POST" action="/api.php">
    <input type="text" name="usertext" value="" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
</form>
```

Which, when the user submits the form, would make a post request to the server at `/api.php`.

If you only want to keep it temporarily, you could load the data into a cookie, or use localstorage.

Comment: I think OP wants to do this without page reloading

Comment: @PhpDev That's why I said you could use jquery to make a post and trigger it on something. That said, it's not very clear, and hence why I added the extra detail (which is much simpler).